# Nesting a Select Distinct and returning all results from Joined tables

Tags: sql, select, join, nested

I have two tables they both have `MemberId` in common. I only want to return the distinct accounts that have a balance greater than 0.00 and a billing notify = 2 where the results are after a certain date. What I have come up with so far is:

```
use Plantation
select tblmember_v62.Acct, tblmember_v62.First, tblmember_v62.Last, tblMemberAccount_v62.Balance
from tblmember_v62, tblMemberAccount_v62
Where dbo.tblMember_v62.MemberId = tblmemberaccount_v62.MemberId
and tblMemberAccount_v62.Balance > '0.00' and tblMember_v62.BillingNotify = '2'
and (tblMemberAccount_v62.InsertDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' or tblMemberAccount_v62.UpdateDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000')
Order by dbo.tblMemberAccount_v62.MemberId, tblmember_v62.Last
```

How can I only return the distinct results? I know it shouldn't be that hard.....

Answer (score 0):

```
use Plantation

select distinct tblmember_v62.Acct, tblmember_v62.First, tblmember_v62.Last, tblMemberAccount_v62.Balance

from tblmember_v62, tblMemberAccount_v62

Where dbo.tblMember_v62.MemberId = tblmemberaccount_v62.MemberId
and tblMemberAccount_v62.Balance > '0.00' and tblMember_v62.BillingNotify = '2'
and (tblMemberAccount_v62.InsertDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' or tblMemberAccount_v62.UpdateDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000')

Order by dbo.tblMemberAccount_v62.MemberId, tblmember_v62.Last
```